# Facebook Comments - Migrated to new wordpress installation and lost all comments

Tags: facebook, wordpress, migration, comments, facebook-comments

I just made a fresh wordpress installation inside my server (garotasgeeks.com)
I'm using the same database info, just changed the folder hiearchy, from a subdirectory to the main directory.
For reasons i don't know why, facebook comments plugin for wordpress is not showing the older comments, just the new ones. But when logged inside the facebook app developers, i can see the older comments.
Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: What was your old URL of website and whats your new URL?

Comment: old: garotasgeeks.com/wordpress
new: garotasgeeks.com

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

`<fb:like href="http://[domain_name]/[old_path]" ></fb:like>`

In your case:

`<fb:like href="http://garotasgeeks.com/wordpress" ></fb:like>`

Comment: not following you dude.. the comment code inside the page is:
<fb:comments-count href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>"></fb:comments-count>

not sure what you're telling me to do;